# How to remove space between lines and replace columns in C# Console

Tags: c#, console

I've tried to remove space between lines and replace columns to align all. I did lots of examples with \t but nothing work. I still have something like this: [c# console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GkKPv.png)

Could you help me? 
My code is:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
Console.WriteLine("Size\tLMaxI\tLMaxT");
for (int ArraySize = 50000; ArraySize <= 500000; ArraySize += 50000)
{
 Console.Write(ArraySize);
 TestVector = new int[ArraySize];
 for (int i = 0; i < TestVector.Length; ++i)
 TestVector[i] = i;
 LinearMaxInstr(); 
 LinearMaxTim(); 

}
}


static void LinearMaxInstr()
{
 OpComparisonEQ = 0;
 bool Present = IsPresent_LinearInstr(TestVector, TestVector.Length - 1);
 Console.Write("\t" + OpComparisonEQ);
}
static void LinearMaxTim()
{
 OpComparisonEQ = 0;
 bool Present = IsPresent_LinearInstr(TestVector, TestVector.Length - 1);
 Console.Write("\t" + OpComparisonEQ);
}
```

Comment: Please, read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: better to give another \t to accomodate the last column value as it has a value large than 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine("{0,6}{1,6}{2,6}", "Size", "LMaxI", "LMaxT");
  for (int ArraySize = 50000; ArraySize <= 500000; ArraySize += 50000)
  {
     Console.Write("{0,6}", ArraySize);
     TestVector = new int[ArraySize];
     for (int i = 0; i < TestVector.Length; ++i)
     TestVector[i] = i;
     LinearMaxInstr(); 
     LinearMaxTim(); 
     Console.Write("\n");
   }
}


static void LinearMaxInstr()
{
 OpComparisonEQ = 0;
 bool Present = IsPresent_LinearInstr(TestVector, TestVector.Length - 1);
 Console.Write("{0,6}", OpComparisonEQ);
}
static void LinearMaxTim()
{
 OpComparisonEQ = 0;
 bool Present = IsPresent_LinearInstr(TestVector, TestVector.Length - 1);
 Console.Write("{0,6}",OpComparisonEQ);
}
```